# SURF algorithm failing?

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, signal-processing, computer-vision

I am currently working on misalignment correction and after some research found a nice [matlab toolbox](http://iatool.net/) for this purpose capable of doing Lucas-Kanade, ECC among others. I had success when using a hybrid method (features via SURF then RANSAC and use the RANSAC warp matrix as initialization of ECC) with some of their test images. However when using images more relevant to my case (a skull xray such the seen [here](http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/BOOKS/Pix/pictures/2012/10/30/1351603919741/Skull-x-ray-010.jpg)) the SURF algorithm fails to find any features. I figured it may be because my ROI was located in the flatter side of the skull so it made sense that nothing was there. But when using the full image or other areas I still get no features. Does anybody know of any book, article or report where the limitations of the SURF algorithm are discussed/tested?

Answer (score 0):

While I have not found a solution as to WHY the implemented versions of the algorithm was failing I have found another implementation where it is much easier to tweak parameters solving my problem (not enough features per image). It is OpenSURF for matlab and can be found [here](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf--including-image-warp-).